# I'd like to get suplicated column name with PDO from query result

Tags: php

I have a query like,

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mysummary", $username, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
$dbh->query("SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 250000");
$dbh->query("set @sql = null");
$dbh->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
        'MAX(IF(binna = ''', binna, ''', `value`, NULL)) AS ', CONCAT(\"`\",binnu ,\"`\")) ORDER BY se ASC
    ) INTO @sql
    FROM `summarypt`.`IMSY` ORDER BY se DESC;");
$dbh->query("SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT W_id, ', @sql, ' FROM 
                    `summarypt`.`IMSY` GROUP BY W_id ORDER BY W_id');");

$dbh->query("PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;");
$result = $dbh->query("EXECUTE stmt")->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

which gives a result like on MySQL workbench
(I made the query with MySQL workbench and ported to PHP)

```
id    2    2    3    4
1    21   null  0    0
2    null  7    0    0
3    null  9    0    0
```

My problem is here. I can't get the column name (id   2   2   3   4) with my php codes. I tried FETCH_NUM, FETCH_ASSOC, FETCH_BOTH but they didn't give me the column name I want from the array keys of $result.
Please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: @shingo I think table can't have duplicated column name. I think the article do not show the way how to get duplicated column name form query result. I want to get duplicated column name from "query result" like the above.

Answer (score 0):

Try [getColumnMeta](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php)

```
$stmt = $dbh->query("EXECUTE stmt");
$count = $stmt->columnCount();
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $colMeta = $stmt->getColumnMeta($i);
    // $colMeta['name']
}
```